# Selectind DOM elements based on attribute content

Tags: php, dom, xquery, domdocument

I have several types of `<a>` in my document. I'd like to select only the `<a>` whose `title` attribute begins with the text "more data ..." like `<a title="more data *">`

For example given the markup below, I'd like to select the first and second `<a>`, but skip the third because `title` doesn't begin with `more data`, and skip the 4th because `<a>` doesn't even have a title attribute.

```
<a title="more data some text" href="http://mypage.com/page.html">More</a>
<a title="more data other text" href="http://mypage.com/page.html">More</a>
<a title="not needed" href="http://mypage.com/page.html">Not needed</a>
<a href="http://mypage.com/page.html">Not needed</a>
```

I'm using DOMXPath. How would my query look like?

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$q = $xpath->query('//a');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a query like:

```
//a[starts-with(@title, "more data ")]
```

Which uses a [**predicate**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates) such that the `title` attribute's value must [**start with**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-starts-with) the specified string.

---

**An example**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML('<example>
<a title="more data some text" href="http://mypage.com/page.html">More</a>
<a title="more data other text" href="http://mypage.com/page.html">More</a>
<a title="not needed" href="http://mypage.com/page.html">Not needed</a>
<a href="http://mypage.com/page.html">Not needed</a>
</example>');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$links = $xpath->query('//a[starts-with(@title, "more data ")]');

echo "Found {$links->length} links", PHP_EOL;
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

And [**here's the above example running online**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fRM5sF).